# Выдаёт ошибку ld return 1 exit status в компиляторе mingw пишу в sablime вот код

Tags: mingw

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib");

#define width 420
#define height 320

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


int WINAPI WinPain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevHinstans, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int CmdShow)
{

    HWND hWnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS w;

    memset(&w, 0, sizeof(w));

    w.style = 0;
    w.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    w.hInstance = hInstance;
    w.lpszClassName = "Windows Form";
    RegisterClass(&w);
    hWnd = CreateWindow(w.lpszClassName, "Form", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~WS_THICKFRAME & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, width, height, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, CmdShow);

    while(GetMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0 ))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LONG WINAPI WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возможно у Вас программа уже запущена, а вы хотите запустить еще. Посмотрите в процессах

Comment: нет она не запущенна

Answer (score 0):

Замените название функции `WinPain` на `WinMain`.

И на будущее: сообщение об ошибке читайте полностью, а не только последнюю строчку. Там наверняка линковщик (ld) сообщал, что ему конкретно не нравится.